# The colored image turned to have no color and just a grey vector in drawable?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, drawable

I have created a new Image Assets in the Drawable cus I need to insert a new image in my app, but every time I create a new image asset, the output turns to be no colour at all. I've attached the pic of it.[image]

It's confusing and whenever I import it in my layout, it's just grey all over as you can see in the image. Why is it cus I can't find any ready solutions? Let me know if I'm overlooked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I got the answer for my own question which I find it's useful for some who still do not know how to enable the ***Batch Drawable Import***. It's easy and just need to download plugin and install. I've read that the latest version already has it and I've downloaded and reinstalled, but it didn't show as what I was expecting. The solution is to download and install it.

> 1. First, In Android Studio, go to Default Setting **File --> Setting** or you can simple **Click** the **SDK Manager Icon**  [image]
> 2. In the Default Setting, go to Plugins [image]
> 3. In the search option, type **Batch Drawable Import** and you'll see there's **Android Drawable Importer**. [image]
> 4. In my image, it's already installed, Click **Install Plugin** and just follow the instructions.
> 5. You'll have to restart Android Studio and try to create a new Batch Drawable Import and you'll find it there. ;) Thanks. [image]

Comment: This is much better solution . in 2016. 5x manual file move for each image is crazy.

Comment: This is a great plugin! Very useful screenshots also!

Comment: this is good solution.. but some images are not getting displayed when trying to add from batch drawable import.. what is solution for it..

Comment: Having problems using batch drawable import plugin on Andoid Studio 3.5 onwards?   Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871334).

Answer (score 16):

While creating a new asset in the drawable folder you need to set the

> "Launcher icons"

in the

> "Asset Type "

drop down
[image]

This will add the images in their original color and will not be greyed out. Also it is possible it adds the images in `res/mipmap` folder. You can move the images from `mipmap` folder to anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks and it works ;)
I've followed one of the answers on here but it didn't work..thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't works at all. When I select "Action Bar and Tab Icons", the image is grey like the question and if I select "Launcher Icons", the image becomes black.

Comment: hey @ChinmaySarupria you can follow my answer below cus it's solved my problem before...

Comment: For me, when I import my images as launcher items, they look great but are unusable as ImageButtons within the app. Am I missing something about the types of images I can import?

Answer (score 2):

I Found the proper solution!
You just have to add this code where you created your **NavigationView** object!

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    //add the line below and your icon will display as your .svg file
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Image Asset as Action bar and Tab icons in the newer version of Android Studio(2.2) it is automatically converted into grey scale,Choose theme from the drop down default is HOLO LIGHT choose custom and you could be able to give the color code,but this works only for sketches kinda images 
 [To get color code](http://www.colorcodepicker.com/)