# Importing image as "Action Bar and Tab Icon" makes image gray

Tags: java, android, image, import

I'm trying to make a temporary image for my app like this: https://i.imgsafe.org/ce378f1.jpg. But when I click **New** -> **Image Asset** and then select "Action Bar and Tab Icons," it becomes a gray image. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The colored image turned to have no color and just a grey vector in drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143020/the-colored-image-turned-to-have-no-color-and-just-a-grey-vector-in-drawable)