# Android Studio not loading image when creating new image asset

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add new image assets to android studio and I have followed a couple of steps to add them correctly, but the IDE is not loading the image.

I have followed these [steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCIG.gif)

Here is my [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDzUY.png) of following those steps. The image is just greyed like that and even if I finish adding it, it's still grey on the components.

Thanks

Comment: try to clean & rebuild your project

Comment: @Munir I just tried it and the results are still the same. The only thing that appears is that grey box in the preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plugin for Android Studio.

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins.
2. Search 'Android Drawable Importer' and Install.
3. Restart Android Studio.

Now you can use Batch Drawable Import in dropdown menu
[image]

You can see how to do it step by step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143020/the-colored-image-turned-to-have-no-color-and-just-a-grey-vector-in-drawable)

or

Set "Launcher icons" in "Icon Type" in Asset Import window.
This will add the images in their original color and will not be greyed out.

Comment: Does it auto-generate the xxhdpi and those type of pd images and all the configuration as well?

Comment: Yes, it generates in all sizes. hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Comment: I tried it and it seems to be working. I marked it as the solution until someone else solves why the IDE's import isn't working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour.

> Action Bar icons are flat, pictured face on, and generally greyscale, depending on the application's theme. Action Bar icons should not look three-dimensional.
>
> In order to maintain consistency across the application's Action Bar, all Action Bar icons should use the same color palette and effects.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Comment: I read that, but I still don't understand why the actual image is not being drawn. Could you please provide an example to make it draw the image?