# Cannot Create Image Asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am on trying to add an Image Asset to my Android project. However, it keeps having this error about a file I don't even have selected.

I am on Android Studio 3.2

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i faced the same issue this happen because of you deleted graddinet.psd file for solve this issue just put that file again and issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where that gradient.psd came from but you may want to take a look at this solution here: [Android Studio not loading image when creating new image asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318863/android-studio-not-loading-image-when-creating-new-image-asset)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem while importing [Google logo](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) and I worked around by having the **Icon Type** as **Launcher Icons (Legacy Only)**