# Adding custom location icon in mapbox - Image appears black and white

Tags: android, mapbox, drawable, qemu, mapbox-android

I'm trying to add a custom icon for the user's location marker in the map. But the icon shows up as black and white.

[image]

```
LocationComponentOptions customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
        .foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.android)
        .build();
// Get an instance of the component
LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

// Activate with options
locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
        LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
                .build());

// Enable to make component visible
locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

// Set the component's camera mode
locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

// Set the component's render mode
locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
```

I tried the chosen answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143020/the-colored-image-turned-to-have-no-color-and-just-a-grey-vector-in-drawable), but it didn't work. I tried using a jpg instead of a png, and again nothing changed.

If I run it on an actual device, it works fine. So I guess the issue is with the emulator.

Comment: Correct, this is an issue with an emulator only. Check out this workaround - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10829#issuecomment-441021598.

Comment: @ŁukaszPaczos Can you add that as an answer? I would like to close the issue.

Comment: Sure, just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this is an issue with an emulator only. Check out this workaround - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10829#issuecomment-441021598.