# Why does Android Drawable Importer ignore selection in AS 3.5 onwards

Tags: android-studio, drawable

After *right-click --> new Batch Drawable Import* and selecting any **.png** from the *Select Image Asset(s)* box, the primary *Batch Drawable Importer* box remains empty (ie: the selection was ignored!).

First 2 lines of Event Log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAllResourceDirectories()Ljava/util/List;
    at de.mprengemann.intellij.plugin.androidicons.util.AndroidFacetUtils.getResourcesRoot(AndroidFacetUtils.java:48)
```

So apparently [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer/versions)  is fundamentally broken under the more recent AS / intellij versions.

I downloaded and re-installed **android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin-0.5-81.zip** to no effect. This plugin was last built in 2016.

This leaves me stuck, because the new *Android Studio Resource Manager* **Import Drawables** function does not allow me to pick an external 256x256 .png and then automatically resize for mdpi, hdpi, xdhpi etc.

I have noted the issue (see comment).

Any circumventions or alternatives?

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin/issues/165).

Answer (score 36):

There were multiple issues preventing operation of this plugin in later releases of Android Studio.

**Update: December 2022**

[Forked](https://github.com/MPArnold/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin), fixed and tested under Android Studio **Dolphin**.

Download the plugin installation zip from [here](https://github.com/MPArnold/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin/releases/download/v0.81/ADI-hack-0.81.zip).

( *AS -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install from disk* )

**Tip**: Uninstall the old version beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For recent Android Studio Versions (tested with 2022.1.1) you can batch import drawables with the built in Resource Manager:
**View > Tool Windows > Resource Manager**
On the + Icon you find "Import Drawables"

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager