# Android Drawable Importer plugin not working in Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

I have updated my Android Studio to `version 3.6`
(Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805). This issue is with the Android Drawable Importer plugin which is no longer working. I tried reinstalling it with no luck.

Comment: It might be an incompatibility issue. Since AS v3.6 was only released two days ago, maybe try waiting for a few more days and see if they release an updated version of the plugin. Out of curiosity, when you say it's no longer working, what is the problem specifically?

Comment: Have the same issue, IDE error balloon pops up, forgot to log it but yeah, something's broken

Comment: It might be worth contacting the plugin's creator about it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: @NikosHidalgo thanks for the contribution, will have to wait...but unfortunately the plugin was last updated in 2016, i guess looking for alternatives will be the best way forwad

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this...

Comment: anyone knows the alternatives?

Comment: No solutions as of yet, personally i have resorted to using free web based image generators like https://appiconmaker.co/

Comment: For Android Studio Dolphin see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977314/2376004) answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I found a repository that was Forked from the original plugin.
Vincent Loi created it! And is working fine in Android Studio 3.6.1! (and with Android studio 4.1.1)

Here is the repo [android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/Vincent-Loi/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

And [here you can download](https://gpskaihu.nz/ADI-hack/ADI-hack-plugin-AS36.zip) the plugin.

Note from Vincent Loi:

> This fork came about because the original package stopped working somewhere around Android Studio 3.5.
> I have provided an installation zip here. As at 31Jan2020 it is known to run nicely on AS 3.6 RC 1. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for this saved my bacon

Comment: For those asking for the steps to install the zip file into Android Studio follow the steps outlined by @Adesuyi Ayodeji below

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally down-voted this answer and I realized it after the vote was locked in, I've actually found it super useful.

Comment: Great ! Thanks you

Comment: Unfortunately plugin is not available on IntelliJ market, You have to download it from the mentioned link and apply it manually from : `Preferences` > `Plugin` > `Settings`(icon) > `Apply plugin from disc`

Comment: You might like to update the links as per my 'Dolphin' answer below. [ I closed the gpsKaihu website months ago].

Answer (score 59):

Found this repo by Vincent Loi on github. You can download from [here](https://gpskaihu.nz/ADI-hack/ADI-hack-plugin-AS36.zip) .

For **BumbleBee** version of Android studio the above plugin wont work. Try this [plugin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgAqKIvQfWKpWZaYui_18kfu6nFcbak_/view?usp=sharing)

To install,

1. Open Android Studio (3.6 RC1) / (BumbleBee +)
2. close all projects
3. click on configure at the lower right corner of the window
4. click on plugin
5. click on install from UDisk in dropdown from top right
6. navigate to where downloaded zip file is located
7. select and restart android studio

EDIT
This also works on Android Studio 4.0.0. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @Adesuyi Ayodeji for your contribution

Comment: No need to 2. close all projects. Just go to `Preferences -> Plugins` and find a gear icon, then select install from local disk.

Comment: Since I can't edit the answer, I am just gonna leave it here. This answer works on Android Studio 4.0 as well.

Comment: Works on Android Studion 4.1

Comment: For those asking how to stop auto-unzip the intellij file on mac. Go to Safari->Preference. Under "General" tab uncheck "Open “safe” files after downloading".

Comment: this not work now, on android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1, menu not show.

Comment: @IndraAsLesmana Sorry for late reply, Uninstall the former plugin from Vincent Loi. Download from my drive here and repeat the installation process i detailed above.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgAqKIvQfWKpWZaYui_18kfu6nFcbak_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AdesuyiAyodeji i have already working plugin, anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: Works on Android ChipMunk 2021.2.1

Answer (score 7):

Android Drawable Importer will not work with AS 4+

So i use https://appicon.co/ which is very good and easy.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to turn to tab https://appicon.co/#image-sets for images, not square icons.

Comment: Guys listen to @Nirbhay Rana.. I also gave up using Android Drawable Importer. I was able to install, only to see that it doesn't work on android studio 4.+ Use Appicon.co to generate your drawables and use Resource Manager on the left to import them. It's almost easier than android drawable importer.

Answer (score 4):

**No Worry**

You can get from **Jetbrain** Plugin site:

1. Goto This [Jetbrain Plugin Sites](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer/versions/stable) **(which is most trusted)**
2. Accept any terms and Condition if requires
3. Download the required version.

> *I have*
>
> *Android Studio 4.0.0*
>
> *Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20,*
> *2020*
>
> *I have downloaded the Android Drawable Importer 0.5-81 under (2016) **which is stable version and worked for me***

1. Now Open Android Studio.
2. close all projects.
3. click on configure on settings icon.
4. click on plugin.
5. Go to Plugin oprion menu, then click Install from UDISK
6. Find your required file from explorer windows or where you have
   downloaded.
7. Simply Click the Green Color Restart button and Take a coffee Sip

[image]

Voila ,your work has been done now you can see the drawble importer and batch drawable option available on your android studio.

Comment: Android Studio 4.0.1, The batch drawable Import menu doesn't accept(either by dragging and dropping or using the import button) any photos.

Comment: Your solution saved my day. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Android Drawable Importer is no longer supported. You can manual install a fork (described in another answer) or you can use "Material Design Icon Generator" plugin available at Plugin Marketplace in Android Studio setting.

You can get more info on plugin's homepage: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14170-material-design-icon-generator

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio Dolphin**

I have just tested a new binary that has so far run without error under Dolphin.

This is a modification to my original fork as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977314/2376004).