# Batch Drawable importer not working anymore

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I would like to create the different resolution images for Android (xxxhdpi, xxhdpi etc). with Android Drawable Importer. I read that the new versions of Android Studio have difficulties with this plugin (really weird according to my point of view). I followed the steps to install it described in [Android Drawable Importer plugin not working in Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412216/android-drawable-importer-plugin-not-working-in-android-studio-3-6)

However, while the in the menue the "Batch Drawable Import" option is shown (see screenshot)[image] when clicking on it the "Batch Drawable Importer" window apprears (see screenhot) [image]but if you select a picture it is not displayed in the editor (in previous versions of Android Studio it worked without problems). Can you tell me what to do? Or can you recommend another way how I can create the different resolution images out of one image? I'd appreciate every feedback and would be quite thankful for your help.