# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SplashActivity}

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packageName/com.packageName.SplashActivity}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable 
com.packageName:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f07015d
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3900)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4057)
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2407)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:334)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8278)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:582)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1065)
```

Firebase Crashlytics show error like this

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packageName/com.packageName.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.packageName:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f07015d

and, next is

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
> Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f07015e

I've custom SplashActivity with just background and drawable in center on it. Using SplashTheme style like this

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item> <!-- Resource ID #0x7f07015d -->
</style>
```

Here is my splash_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_splash" /> <!-- Resource ID #0x7f0700af -->
    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_icon" android:gravity="center" /> <!-- Resource ID #0x7f07015e -->
</layer-list>
```

Here is my build.gradle configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
compileSdkVersion 33
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.packageName"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode "VERSION_CODE"
    versionName "VERSION_NAME"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
namespace 'com.packageName'
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.1'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'saschpe.android:customtabs:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.3.2'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
}
```

For your information splash_background.xml is available in drawable folder, gradient_splash.xml is available in drawable folder and splash_icon.png is available in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi folders.

Comment: You shall place the .png file in the Resources/drawable folder as a fallback plan.

Comment: I believe the splash_icon.png is not found since the device does not recognise what DPI it is using or somehow it is a "new" DPI. So it will try to lookup the drawable folder (default) for the resource.

Comment: I tried to put splash_icon.png in drawable, drawable-nodpi, drawable-anydpi but still error persist. so I removed from these folders.

Answer (score 0):

In My Opinion, You Need to Use Difference sizes of image drawable like (drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi , etc..)

also you can use [Android Drawable Important](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) to import Drawable with difference size.

may be found an issue with importing this library in the latest version of an android studio so you can see this [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412216/android-drawable-importer-plugin-not-working-in-android-studio-3-6) and use it.

Comment: Hi @Hatem, I'm using different size of images as I mentioned in my question, drawable-mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi but still this exception persist.

Comment: Hello @SanjayS Maybe you are missing one of these type needs for your testing device or emulator 

drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-v24
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
drawable