# Android Drawable Importer in Android Studio Arctic Fox version

Tags: android-drawable-importer

I've updated my Android Studio to "Arctic Fox" version, but "Android Drawable Importer" doesn't work at all. I've installed the plugin, but "Batch Drawable Importer" doesn't show up in the drawable file. Any solutions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed some bug found in Android Studio Arctic Fox , it is working now

Here is the repo [android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/Skeaner/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

you can download [here](https://github.com/Skeaner/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin/releases/download/0.8/ADI-hack-0.8.zip).

Comment: I've created a public GitHub Gist to keep track of working builds for our beloved plugin.

https://gist.github.com/delacrixmorgan/bea305ecc0df3a89e0f05a219efce94f

Comment: Also works on current Bublebee build!

Comment: For Android Studio Dolphin see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977314/2376004).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I uninstalled and intalled again from .zip and got a message: `Plugin 'Android Drawable Importer' (version 0.5-81) was explicitly marked as incompatible with the current version of the IDE`.