# Is it okay to ignore "IDE error occurred" if I know what is causing the problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

So I have installed an external plugin from disk "Android drawable importer" and when I use Android Studio with this plugin the "IDE error occurred" is shown. I have noticed that if I disable the plugin, the IDE error disappears. So if I know that the error is caused by the plugin, if I ignore it, would there be any problem if it is shown? Or it could affect the proper functioning of my app?

Answer (score 0):

> if I ignore it, would there be any problem if it is shown?

We have no way of knowing what impact there is on your IDE or that plugin from whatever the error is.

> Or it could affect the proper functioning of my app?

It should not affect your app directly. Your IDE might not work, or the plugin might not work. Those things might affect your ability to write the app.

To draw an analogy, suppose that instead of showing "IDE error occurred", your development computer caught on fire due to whatever the problem is. That does not affect your app, other than by how it affects your ability to write the app, given that your computer is on fire.

Comment: So it is okay if I use the plugin to create different drawables-densities and after using the plugin disable it to continue working with my app without any problem? I mean, what I have understood about your awnser is that it wont affect my app but can affect me while creating the app, is that correct?

Comment: @Eldestornillador: "So it is okay if I use the plugin to create different drawables-densities and after using the plugin disable it to continue working with my app without any problem?" -- probably, but we have no way to know. "it wont affect my app but can affect me while creating the app, is that correct?" -- correct.

Comment: I have edited the question with the errors that it is howing me, could that help to solve my previous awnser or that is not relevant?

Comment: @Eldestornillador: The error indicates that your plugin is using some old API that is no longer supported. Make sure that you are on the latest version of the plugin. If the plugin is no longer being maintained, then eventually it will stop working entirely, most likely.

Comment: so what does it mean that it is no longer supported? If this plugin creates different image-densities, could they be creating in a wrong way or something like that? If I have seen that it is apparently working would there be any problem? I don´t understand what problems could I have if it is using some old API..

Comment: @Eldestornillador: "so what does it mean that it is no longer supported?" -- the plugin is created by a programmer. If that programmer is not updating the plugin for newer versions of the IDE, eventually the two will no longer work together. The error that you are seeing is a warning that this will happen in the future.

Comment: so imagine that in the future it is not working together with the IDE, how can I know that day has come? I mean if that is a warning, if one day it stops working , will Android Studio show a different error message? I am confused because I thought that the IDE error as the name says is an error, not a warning..

Comment: @Eldestornillador: "if one day it stops working , will Android Studio show a different error message?" -- possibly. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the binary you downloaded and the version of Android Studio you are running various "IDE error" events may occur.

If you are using Android Studio Dolphin use the binary noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977314/2376004) answer.