# How can I import a color image into Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android-studio, import, android-drawable, android-studio-3.6.1

For some reason all images I import to my android studio project are gray scale. Previously I found a solution here:

[The colored image turned to have no color and just a grey vector in drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143020/the-colored-image-turned-to-have-no-color-and-just-a-grey-vector-in-drawable)

But apparently the batch drawable importer stopped working in Android Studio 3.6. Is there another solution I am unaware of?

Edit: Do I need to give more information or am I just the only one with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? "color image"

Comment: I was having the same problem that is listed in the article I linked. Everytime I add an image asset, it becomes a gray scale version of what I'm trying to upload and the solution in the article no longer works as of version 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot more looking and if you click on "resource monitor" on the left (for me) there is a "plus" sign that you can select to add drawables. Depending on the file type, it will correctly import the drawable as a full color image